# Solving coupled differential equation via perturbation method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

In the paper by Caroli, de-Gennes and Matricon on Bound fermion state in superconductor, they have reached a system of first order differential equation which reads roughly as:
\begin{align}
-i\hbar v_F\frac{df}{dr}+\Delta(r)g(r)&=(\epsilon+\frac{\mu\hbar^2}{2mr^2})f(r) 
\\
i\hbar v_F\frac{dg}{dr}+\Delta(r)f(r)&=(\epsilon+\frac{\mu\hbar^2}{2mr^2})g(r) 
\\[.5em]
v_F&=\frac{\hbar k_F}{m}
\end{align}
$f(r),g(r), \Delta(r)$ are functions of $r$.

$\mu$ is an integer and $\epsilon$ is a small number and can be treated as a small perturbation.

What I fail to understand is how they are able to solve the above system by treating the right hand side as a small perturbation, to first order, and obtain the following results:
\begin{align}
f(r)&=e^{\frac{1}{2}i\psi(r)-K(r)}\\
g(r)&=-ie^{-\frac{1}{2}i\psi(r)-K(r)}
\end{align}
where $$K(r)=\frac{\int_{0}^{r}\Delta(r')dr'}{\hbar v_F}$$
and $$\psi(r)=-e^{2K(r)}\int_{r}^{\infty}e^{-K(r')}(\frac{2\epsilon}{\hbar v_F}+\frac{\mu}{k_Fr'^2})dr'$$
If someone can explain briefly the procedure to get to the final results, it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to answer.

Comment: You can get proper parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Can you include a link to the paper in the body of the question?

Comment: @Axion004 Here is the link [Bound Fermion states on a vortex line in a type II superconductor](https://doi.org/10.1016/0031-9163(64)90375-0)